# I need to disable a function while timer is running

Tags: vb.net, function, timer

I am working on a project that is for an image hosting site and I need to find a way so that when a function is called by the user hitting the hotkeys it will trigger a timer for x amount of seconds that will disable that function from being called.

I already have the function setup and the hotkeys all I need to add is disabling the function from being called inside the timer while it is ticking. Any ideas? Or is it possible?

Best Regards & Many Thanks, Aurora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set a Boolean Variable before you start your Timer then reset it in your Timer's Tick EventHandler.

Something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim disableFunction As Boolean = False
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Timer1.Interval = 2000 '2 second wait time
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
        disableFunction = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If disableFunction Then Exit Sub
        disableFunction = True
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you once again, Mark. This worked like a charm and on that note. My program is finished. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim run As Boolean
Sub tick() Handles Timer.Tick
    If run Then
        callfunction()
    End If
End Sub
```